# Enable if/else class member template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Can anyone tell my how to enable if/else class member template based on different derived classes from pre-defined base set? Let me use the following example:

```
enum class Type {
  TYPEA,
  TYPEB
};

// Predefined in libraries.
class BaseA {...};
class BaseB {...};

class Foo {
  template <typename Derived, Type type>
  void foo();
};

// User-derived
class DerivedA : public BaseA {};
class DerivedB : public BaseB {};
```

Normally we need two template typenames for calling the member foo.

```
Foo obj;
obj.foo<DerivedA, Type::TypeA>()
obj.foo<DerivedB, Type::TypeB>();
```

However, this native approach seems lengthy because the second template argument `Type::TypeA` and `Type::TypeB` can obviously be deduced by compiler through the first argument `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`, if they are derived from pre-defined base properly. I notice that c++11 provides `is_base_of` template but I am not sure how to use it in my case. To be more specific, below is the expected solution:

```
obj.foo<DerivedA>();  // Automatically deduce type = Type::TypeA
obj.foo<DerivedB>();  // Automatically deduce type = Type::TypeB
```

And if the compile fails to deduce the `Type` from the first typename, it should it just goes back to the normal declaration `obj.foo<MyClass, MyType>` where `MyType` is either `Type::TypeA` or `Type::TypeB`.

Comment: How does `DerivedA` know that its `Type` is `TypeA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<Type t>
using etype_tag = std::integral_constant<Type, t>;

template<class T>
struct tag_t {
  using type=T;
  template<class D,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T, D>::value, int>* =nullptr
  >
  constexpr tag_t( tag_t<D> ) {}
  constexpr tag_t() = default;
  constexpr tag_t(tag_t const&) = default;
};

template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};


constexpr etype_tag<Type::TYPEA> get_etype( tag_t<BaseA> ) { return {}; }
constexpr etype_tag<Type::TYPEB> get_etype( tag_t<BaseB> ) { return {}; }

template<class T>
constexpr decltype( get_etype( tag<T> ) ) etype{};
```

Now `etype<Bob>` is a compile-time constant integral constant you want.

```
class Foo {
  template <typename Derived, Type type=etype<Derived>>
  void foo();
};
```

makes the 2nd argument (usually) redundant.

You can extend `get_etype` with more overloads in either the namespace where `etype` is declared, or in the namespace of `tag_t`, or in the namespace of the type you are extending `get_etype` to work with, and `etype` will automatically gain support (assuming it is used in a context where the extension is visible: failure of that requirement leaves your program ill formed).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/453e84ce9f59761c)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want a default template argument:

```
class Foo {
  template <typename Derived, Type type = get_type_from<Derived>::value>
  void foo();
};
```

Where `get_type_from<>` is a metafunction to be filled in later based on how you actually figure out the `Type`s.